# how to trim and save in variable upto first space in string in javascript

Tags: javascript

[response data in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BNQN.png)
I'm getting data mixed with latitude , longitude , altitude and speed in a single string. i want to segregate all 4 in 4 variables. I'm trying with index of but getting -1 in place of latitude, how to trim it properly

response data
[response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rarI4.png)

Sample data

```
["13.8650839 78.5766843 867.699951171875 0.0"]
```

Expected output

```
latitude=13.8650839
longitude=78.5766843
altitude=867.699951171875
speed=0.0
```

code

```
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
      var responsedata = this.responseText;
      const data = responsedata;
      const [latitude, longitude, altitude, speed] = data[0].split(' ');
      console.log(latitude, longitude, altitude, speed);
      alert(latitude);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the array at the spaces and assign them to variables like so, refer here to know more about [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = '["12.8651929 77.576346 946.1199908085856 0.0"]';

const [latitude, longitude, altitude, speed] = JSON.parse(data)[0].split(' ');

console.log(latitude, longitude, altitude, speed);
```

Comment: but im getting [ undefined undefined undefined in console.do i need to initialize the variables.

Comment: @krishnamohan can you console.log the data and check it should be the same as `["13.8650839 78.5766843 867.699951171875 0.0"]` it should be an array with a string inside

Comment: ["12.8651929�77.576346�946.1199908085856�0.0"]. when i directly hit the url in the brower im getting like this. but in console im getting space .

Comment: @krishnamohan Check the API why we are getting it like so, for now you can do a split at `�`, then the code will work fine, but this needs to be fixed in API side

Comment: const [latitude, longitude, altitude, speed] = data[0].split('"�"');
like this i tried. no luck

Comment: @krishnamohan Updated answer based on the data from API.

Comment: can u please check once the response i have checked from the console. i have updated in question. i tried with the symbol not worked. may be the  double quotes is the issue.

Comment: @krishnamohan Youre getting a string not an array, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method in js to get the array like this

```
const str = ['13.8650839 78.5766843 867.699951171875 0.0'];

const words = str[0].split(' ')
console.log(words);
```

Now you get ouptut like this

```
Array ["13.8650839", "78.5766843", "867.699951171875", "0.0"]
```

Now you can extract easily you data using array index..